# Comparison of Columns between two tables with different filters

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following code that I am using to compare two columns from different tables, the code almost runs perfectly if I don't have any `where` clauses/filters in my code below.

If I add the where clause I do get extra rows that I don't want to see.

```
with source1 as (
select 
b.id, 
b.qty, 
a.price 
from <table> as a
,unnest <details> as b
 where b.status != 'canceled'
),

source2 as (
select id_, qty_, price_  from <table2>
where city != 'delhi'
) 

select *
from source1 s1
full outer join source2 s2
on id = id_
where format('%t', s1) != format('%t', s2)
```

Below is the sample data:

**s1:**

```
id  qty   price   status
1   100 (null)    canceled
2   0     100       done
3   0      80       canceled
4   50     90       done
5   20    100       done
6   20    100       done
7   80     80       done
8   100   100       canceled
9   40     0        done
10  11     22       done
11  40     40       done
12  null   90       done
```

**s2:**

```
id_ qty_    price_  city_
1   100     200     ny
2   0       100     ny
3   0        80     ny
4   50       80     ny
5   40      100     ny
6   40       40     ny
7   200     200  delhi
8   100     100  delhi
9   40      100     ny
10  11       22  delhi
12  11       11     ny
13  90       80     NY
```

**Expected Results:**

```
id  qty    price    status       id_    qty_    price_  city_
4   50        90    done          4       50    80      ny
5   20       100    done          5       40    100     ny
6   20       100    done          6       40    40      ny
9   40         0    done          9       40    100     ny
11  40        40    done       null     null    null    null
12  null      90    done         12       11    11      ny
null null   null    null         13       90    80      ny
```

- In general, I want all the rows that have at least one mismatch in any of the columns **(qty, price, status)** but only when the status is not canceled or city is not equal to delhi and show the values of both tables (s1,s2) for each column in a single row (as shown in expected results)
- If a row exists in one table and not the other and doesn't have `status = canceled` or `city = delhi`, then it should show up
- if the `city != delhi` and `status != canceled` and the values are same for (qty,price,status) then, I **don't** want that row ***

**Current issues:**

`where status != 'canceled'` -- *this will exclude all the rows with cases = canceled from source 1 **but my source2 will still show the rows** where the status is actually canceled, and will bring that row up which I don't want

similarly, `source2` has a condition: `where city != 'delhi'` and source1 not, **this will again show rows which i don't want**

If I pass the column `status` and `city` in the `select` statements of my codes above (code 1 and code 2) it will be passed in the condition: `where format('%t', s1) != format('%t', s2)` and so each time there will be a mismatch since city column doesn't exist in source1 and status one in the source2. The string/serial generated will not be able to match for example:

**s1:**

```
id, qty, price, status
1   10   100   cancelled
```

**s2:**

```
id_ qty_ price_  city
1    10   100    Delhi
```

`where format('%t', s1) != format('%t', s2)` would generate:

`(1,10,100,cancelled) != (1,10,100,delhi)`

in this case, the columns have the same values (qty, price, status) but the row will still show up which I don't want due to the issue explained above.

**Questions:**

- Is there a way I can pass specific columns to the part `format('%t',s2)`, instead of passing the entire table name, that should solve the problem ? If I can somehow not let the status and city be part of serialization
- How can I tackle the where clauses / filters in these cases, right now I only have one filter for each table but it can be more in the future.
- How can I get the expected output ? I would prefer not to use any other method apart from this serialization i.e **format('%t', s2)**  (if possible) as I already have most of the code and would like to adjust it to cover all the cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can pass specific columns to the part format('%t',s2), instead of passing the entire table name, that should solve the problem ? If I can somehow not let the status and city be part of serialization

just use below

```
where format('%t', (id, qty, price)) != format('%t', (id_, qty_, price_))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, is there a better way to format it, considering there could be 10/15 columns ? The code would look really bad in that case if I pass multiple columns on each side

Comment: can you please confirm, if this would solve the problem to get the expected results:  in my last step I will change to the following: `where format('%t', (id, qty, price)) != format('%t', (id_, qty_, price_)) and status != 'canceled' or city != 'delhi'` , that means I will pass the status and city column in my select statements and not use them from serialization, or is there a better way to solve this

Comment: I think this is the best way to not to use them in the serialization!